# Is there a way to don't include .so file if I use created ndk lib?

Tags: android, android-ndk, lib, ndk-build

I created Android lib that use NDK ArCore

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/enable-arcore

Then I built a lib and got `.aar` file. Then I created new sample project and included this `.aar` file like a module (import .JAR/.AAR package) and linked it like dependency, so all works fine.

Issue is - when I try to call method that use `ArCore` I am getting such error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ar, PID: 7822
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libarcore_sdk_c.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at com..libtetplayer.JniInterface.<clinit>(JniInterface.java:32)
        at com..libtetplayer.JniInterface.createNativeApplication(Native Method)
        at com.example.ar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6990)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

In order to fix it: 
After I build my lib there are some autogenerated files under build dir, there I found `arcore-native` dir and there four dirs

[image]

I just moved this source to my sample project under the `main` dir and now it is completely works

**Question** is - is there is a way to don't include this dirs with `.so` files in project when implementing the lib? Maybe I need to include them directly to lib somehow?

**P.S.** Because it is a little bit hard everytime ask user that want to implement my lib also include a few dirs with `.so` files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `.so` files from **arcore-native** in your `.aar` file and they will be delivered with your lib.

Comment: It sounds right, but now AS says that it has more then one `.so` file... I posted another question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58969292/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-lib-armeabi-v7a-libarcore

Comment: I am confused. The `.aar` file is for the library that you deliver. This library should not need `com.google.ar:core` dependency anymore, it should have ARCore bundled inside.