# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, arcore

I know there is a few similar questions on SO, but it does not work for me...

I created Android lib, that use ArCore. It was a question on SO how to don't include .so file if I use created ndk lib? There is also one answer that sounds right

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58963852/5709159

But after I putted `libarcore.so` files under my `jniLib`

[image]

I got such error

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'

So, I tried to fix it this ways

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962630/5709159

```
sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453718/5709159

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
    pickFirst 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
    pickFirst 'src/main/jniLibs/x86/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
    pickFirst 'src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
}
```

then this

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
}
```

and also this 
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libarcore_sdk_jni.so'
    }

Nothing helped.

As far as I understand issue is - I have one copy of `arcore.so` files under my `jniLibs` dir and one copy created after `Build` here

[image]

So, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You've likely added the shared `.so` files **and** build from source (or reference them otherwise).

One cannot do both at the same time, so you'd either need to build from [source](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk) and delete those `.so` files - or delete the `arcore-android-sdk` module and keep the `.so` files. Java `dependencies` might also pull in native assembly, while that part of the `build.gradle` is missing (just browse AR core in the "External Libraries" to see what it contains, in case it exists there). Using pre-built libraries generally builds quicker and saves time - which is suggested, unless needing to edit `cpp` sources.

Usually one can provide the dependencies alike in this [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/hello_ar_c/app/build.gradle):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.ar:core:1.13.0"
    natives "com.google.ar:core:1.13.0"
}

// Extracts the shared libraries from aars in the natives configuration.
// This is done so that NDK builds can access these libraries.
task extractNativeLibraries() {
    // Always extract, this ensures the native libs are updated if the version changes.
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    doFirst {
        configurations.natives.files.each { f ->
            copy {
                from zipTree(f)
                into arcore_libpath
                include "jni/**/*"
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded {
    task-> if (task.name.contains("external") && !task.name.contains("Clean")) {
        task.dependsOn(extractNativeLibraries)
    }
}
```

Such Gradle task could also be the reason for the duplicates, when it's not configured properly. `packagingOptions` are in every case the wrong approach, when the linker already doesn't know which one to link.

Answer (score 0):

this solution will work

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210#issuecomment-1304536693

adding the below code in android/gradle

```
  def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        // Remove this override in 0.66, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
        force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
    }
}
```